# Get authentication token from azure ad and use in controller class

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage

I have a demo rest api created with spring boot. In which using POST endpoint.
How can i get access token from Azure AD and use that in spring boot demo application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the step-by-step guide give given by Microsoft which have every thing you required to implement Authentication in Azure Active Directory using Spring Boot [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory).

Comment: Followed all steps as per document. Code given in document works fine. But when I added a more method of type POST `addEmployee()` in `HomeController.java` then it just give status code as 200 ok but not going inside method. For testing I have a logger inn method `Inside add employee method` but it is not getting printed and also debug is not coming here . Can you share example of POST mapping using the example mentioned in document you shared @Hari

Comment: Hi @javageekssb,In ms graph we have the ability to do post ,patch and put requests directly.Please follow [MS Document](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/wiki/Patching-objects).

Comment: How can I use JWT and Azure AD to secure Spring Boot Rest API endpoint ?

Comment: I read for Patching objects but that is not clear from document. Is there any sample code ?

Comment: .Please ask any new questions as a new stack overflow question as they will help other's with same issue.For patching objects, please go through the sample  [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java)